# How to replace each 0 with the preceding element in a list in an idiomatic way in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is a fun little problem, and I wanted to check with the experts here if there is a better functional/Mathematica way to approach solving it than what I did. I am not too happy with my solution since I use big IF THEN ELSE in it, but could not find a Mathematica command to use easily to do it (such as `Select`, `Cases`, `Sow/Reap`, `Map`.. etc...)

Here is the problem, given a list values (numbers or symbols), but for simplicity, lets assume a list of numbers for now. The list can contain zeros and the goal is replace the each zero with the element seen before it.

At the end, *the list should contain no zeros in it*.

Here is an example, given

```
a = {1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 5, 0};
```

the result should be

```
a = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 5}
```

It should ofcourse be done in the most efficient way.

This is what I could come up with

```
Scan[(a[[#]] = If[a[[#]] == 0, a[[#-1]], a[[#]]]) &, Range[2, Length[a]]];
```

I wanted to see if I can use Sow/Reap on this, but did not know how.

**question: can this be solved in a more functional/Mathematica way? The shorter the better ofcourse :)**

**update 1**
Thanks everyone for the answer, all are very good to learn from. This is the result of speed test, on V 8.04, using windows 7, 4 GB Ram, intel 930 @2.8 Ghz:

I've tested the methods given for `n` from `100,000` to `4 million`. The `ReplaceRepeated` method does not do well for large lists.

**update 2**

Removed earlier result that was shown above in update1 due to my error in copying one of the tests.

The updated results are below. Leonid method is the fastest. Congratulation Leonid. A very fast method.

[image]

The test program is the following:

```
(*version 2.0 *)
runTests[sizeOfList_?(IntegerQ[#] && Positive[#] &)] := 
 Module[{tests, lst, result, nasser, daniel, heike, leonid, andrei, 
   sjoerd, i, names},

  nasser[lst_List] := Module[{a = lst},
    Scan[(a[[#]] = If[a[[#]] == 0, a[[# - 1]], a[[#]]]) &, 
     Range[2, Length[a]]]
    ];

  daniel[lst_List] := Module[{replaceWithPrior},
    replaceWithPrior[ll_, n_: 0] := 
     Module[{prev}, Map[If[# == 0, prev, prev = #] &, ll]
      ];
    replaceWithPrior[lst]
    ];

  heike[lst_List] := Flatten[Accumulate /@ Split[lst, (#2 == 0) &]];

  andrei[lst_List] := Module[{x, y, z},
    ReplaceRepeated[lst, {x___, y_, 0, z___} :> {x, y, y, z}, 
     MaxIterations -> Infinity]
    ];

  leonid[lst_List] := 
   FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1, #2] &, First@#, Rest@#] & @lst;

  sjoerd[lst_List] := 
   FixedPoint[(1 - Unitize[#]) RotateRight[#] + # &, lst];

  lst = RandomChoice[Join[ConstantArray[0, 10], Range[-1, 5]], 
    sizeOfList];
  tests = {nasser, daniel, heike, leonid, sjoerd};
  names = {"Nasser","Daniel", "Heike", "Leonid", "Sjoerd"};

  result = Table[0, {Length[tests]}, {2}];

  Do[
   result[[i, 1]] = names[[i]];

   Block[{j, r = Table[0, {5}]},
    Do[
     r[[j]] = First@Timing[tests[[i]][lst]], {j, 1, 5}
     ];
    result[[i, 2]] = Mean[r]
    ],

   {i, 1, Length[tests]}
   ];

  result
  ]
```

To run the tests for length 1000 the command is:

```
Grid[runTests[1000], Frame -> All]
```

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Just a note that using `If` is *not* not functional.  Conditionals are an essential part of functional programming, and do not require side effects.  Think of `If` as a mathematical function mapping boolans (the set {True,False}) to something else. Otherwise I came up with the same solution as Andrei, which I think is the simplest, but definitely not the fastest (hence not the most practical if you process large data!)

Comment: replaceWithPrior[ll_, n_: 0] := Module[{prev},
  Map[If[# == 0, prev, prev = #] &, ll]]
In[12]:= replaceWithPrior[a]
Out[12]= {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 5}

Comment: BTW what should happen if the first element is 0?

Comment: @Szabolcs, if first element is zero, then the rule does not apply to it, since there is no element before it, hence it is not changed. Also, a list of ALL zeros, will remain ALL zeros. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much (order of magnitude) faster than other solutions still:

```
FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1, #2] &, First@#, Rest@#] &
```

The speedup is due to `Fold` autocompiling. Will not be so dramatic for non-packed arrays. Benchmarks:

```
In[594]:= 
a=b=c=RandomChoice[Join[ConstantArray[0,10],Range[-1,5]],150000];
(b=Flatten[Accumulate/@Split[b,(#2==0)&]]);//Timing
Scan[(a[[#]]=If[a[[#]]==0,a[[#-1]],a[[#]]])&,Range[2,Length[a]]]//Timing
(c=FoldList[If[#2==0,#1,#2]&,First@#,Rest@#]&@c);//Timing

SameQ[a,b,c]

Out[595]= {0.187,Null}
Out[596]= {0.625,Null}
Out[597]= {0.016,Null}
Out[598]= True
```

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a factor 4 faster on my machine:

```
a = Flatten[Accumulate /@ Split[a, (#2 == 0) &]]
```

The timings I get are

```
a = b = RandomChoice[Join[ConstantArray[0, 10], Range[-1, 5]], 10000];

(b = Flatten[Accumulate /@ Split[b, (#2 == 0) &]]); // Timing

Scan[(a[[#]] = If[a[[#]] == 0, a[[# - 1]], a[[#]]]) &, 
  Range[2, Length[a]]] // Timing

SameQ[a, b]

(* {0.015815, Null} *)
(* {0.061929, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: I like the use of `Split` here. I did something similar, but it is slower: `Flatten[Map[ConstantArray[First[#], Length[#]] &, 
  Split[a, #2 == 0 &]]]`

Answer (score 8):

```
FixedPoint[(1 - Unitize[#]) RotateRight[#] + # &, d]
```

is about 10 and 2 times faster than Heike's solutions but slower than Leonid's.

Comment: Are you sure about the slower bit? In all my tests so far, your method was the fastest. I'll post the test code (n case I did something wrong) and table results soon. I am using v 8.04 on windows 7

Comment: @Sjoerd Nice take on it. Efficiency seems to depend on the average size of a run of zeros though (this is from a supericial look at it,  I may be wrong). +1

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks for spotting this. I copied your code from the top of your post, overlooked the extra @ you used below when you applied it. That is why I posted my test code to make sure it got reviewed first. Will re-run all tests and delete current results table and post new results later. quick test shows your is indeed faster now. I am also trying to finish another method myself and will add that to the table. But got to run now get some food before stores close.

Comment: @Leonid Yeah, I realized that that would be the weak spot of my line of code, but I couldn't find a way to get rid  of it. Happy New Year, by the way! It will be a year of change, I feel.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks! Happy New Year for you too! I share your feelings about the changes. Let's hope they will be good ones.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for reposting the results, and for the accept. Your initial usage was slow because space was interpreted as multiplication, and the large numerical list was unpacked . Happy New Year!

Answer (score 6):

You question looks exactly like a task for [ReplaceRepeated](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) function. What it does basically is that it applies the same set of rules to the expression until no more rules are applicable. In your case the expression is a list, and the rule is to replace 0 with its predecessor whenever  occurs in a list. So here is the solution:

```
a = {1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 5, 0};
a //. {x___, y_, 0, z___} -> {x, y, y, z};
```

The pattern for the rule here is the following:

- `x___` - any symbol, zero or more repetitions, the beginning of the list
- `y_` - exactly one element before zero
- `0` - zero itself, this element will be replaced with `y` later
- `z___` - any symbol, zero or more repetitions, the end of the list

Comment: Sorry to bring it, but I feel I should, since no one else commented on this yet. This will generally be very inefficient, and only practical for very short lists. The general advice is to avoid `ReplaceRepeated` with patterns similar to the one you used (involving double and tripple blanks). I mentioned it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721171/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/4723969#4723969, as one of the performance pitfalls. Another note is that you should have used `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule`, to properly localize your pattern variables.

Comment: I found also there is a default limit in using ReplaceRepeated. When I run it on large list, I get the error from the kernel `ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after....scanned 65536 times`. Then I found that this limit can be removed by using `MaxIterations->Infinity` option.

Comment: @Leonid, thanks a lot, didn't now about poor `ReplaceRepeated` performance.

Comment: @Andrei I was bitten by this behavior (slowdown) many times myself. Not only is this slow because the pattern-matcher runs through the whole list to get a single match (which I mentioned in the book), but also rules like `{x_,z__}:>{z}` lead to copying of entire sequence `z`, which is both run-time and memory - inefficient. On a different matter: there is a new Mathematica SE proposal currently in a commitment stage (with a hope to getting into beta soon): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica . If you are interested in Mathematica, consider supporting it.